# Identifying bean dependencies associated with a specific operation

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am working on a JAX-RPC webservice that is already built. This is a huge service which consists of around 25-30 operations. A large number of Spring config files (around 50) are also present. A number of test classes are developed which loads all the spring references associated with the service. This takes a long time to load all the spring config files and associated bean references before executing the specific test method. I am trying to see if I can load only the specific spring config files / bean references that pertain to the operation.

I was told that setting default lazy load parameter in spring config might not help as it works only if it is run within a container. Would it be possible to help in suggesting in options that I can follow to decrease the initial loading time?

Comment: "I was told that...." - give it a try. You were told wrong.

Comment: There a number of spring config files , few of them within jar files that ae loaded. So I would not be able to make changes to those config files - is there a way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but may be this help you. You can use annotations in you test classes to specify the config files you need to include to the context. Also, you can add spring profiles and activate them from the test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({ "dev-test"})
@ContextConfiguration({"/application-context-persistence.xml", "/another-context.xml"})
public class Test{

}
```